# OHAttributedLabel and UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, hyperlink, nsattributedstring

I am using OHAttributedLabel to create a text link inside my UITableViewCell. However, when I am tapping this link, I am having hard time getting the tap through, it seems like I have to hold my finger a lot longer to get OHAttributedLabel to realize that I want to tap the link.

I do not have this problem outside UITableViews, everything works perfectly. Curiously, this same error happens also in tableViewFooter and header. I have set userInteractionEnabled = YES for the label, and NO for the cell. What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: If I recall correctly, I didn't. Looking at my code now, I used TTTAttributedLabel, so probably I found nothing to fix it. TTTAttributedLabel isn't perfect either (no link highlighting when pressed, unless you use the experimental version, which is still a bit buggy), but I decided that I could live with it.